# How can I install ethminer on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, 17.04, ethereum

I was following this guide. https://www.meebey.net/posts/ethereum_gpu_mining_on_linux_howto/

Basically its instructions are like this

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum ethminer
geth account new
# copy long character sequence within {}, that is your <YOUR_WALLET_ADDRESS>
# if you lose the passphrase, you lose your coins!
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-amd64 build-essential
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.35.run
sudo NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.35.run
ethminer -G -F http://yolo.ethclassic.faith:9999/0x<YOUR_WALLET_ADDRESS> --farm-recheck 200
```

On the command `sudo apt-get install ethereum ethminer` it fails with the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ethminer
```

I did follow the instruction of adding the ethereum ppa so I am not sure why it will cannot find the ethminer package. Is the guide just out of date?

Comment: I think the ppa will only work properly on 16.04. Might have to build it from source. Its called cpp-ethereum.
http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/linux.html#building-linux-from-source

Comment: The instructions appear to be bogus or outdated. There's [no `ethminer` package in that PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+packages?field.name_filter=ethminer&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No wonder knowing that you can't install `ethminer` directly from `apt install` command, when I try to find `ethminer` package on [Etherum's launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum), return with no avail. So basically the `ethminer` package doesn't belong to the `ppa`, it's unknown either the instruction article is outdated or other reason.

I suggest you to read this https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining#gpu-mining-with-ethminer, there are tutorials available on how to install `ethminer` from source depending on OS, though I haven't tested this method.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work in 17.04 by downloading the ethminer binary directly from https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/releases

I also had to install the nvidia cuda drivers with this command

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-nsight
```

Answer (score 2):

[I currently understand](https://medium.com/@oconnorct1/getting-started-mining-ethereum-on-ubuntu-january-2017-148c53f8793b) you should use the following:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-qt
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
sudo apt-get install cpp-ethereum
```

But I don't think `cpp-ethereum` is supported for Zesty yet in the ppa's (see [here](https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum-dev)) since `cpp-ethereum` fails to install. Instead download the project from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum) and follow instructions to build from source.

However, according to the build instructions,

> **Mining**
>
> This project is not suitable for Ethereum mining. The support for GPU mining has been dropped some time ago including the ethminer tool. Use the ethminer tool from https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer.

So don't think you actually need `cpp-ethereum`. But I'm just learning this stuff so may update this later. I'm building `cpp-ethereum` on 17.04 as I type !

**UPDATE**

Ok, if I'm to follow [my original tutorial](https://medium.com/@oconnorct1/getting-started-mining-ethereum-on-ubuntu-january-2017-148c53f8793b) and the comment about mining in the build instructions of `cpp-ethereum` then it seems what I actually have to do is build `ethminer` from [here](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer). On with that now. Will update again soon.

**UPDATE**

That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears you're using nvidia:
Install [nvidia driver](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?) and [CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).
Use the nvidia site for this NOT apt depo pkgs.
Grab newest on both. CUDA should be 9.1 at time of this writing.

Download the ethminer release for Linux and [follow instructions](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/blob/master/README.md#install) :

https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/releases

Be wary of the release candidates (RC). At time of this writing 0.12.0 is stable.

The release binary works fine -> tested under 14.04, 16.04 17.04.